# Why my prediction is too different from my testing data?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I have a problem with *Time Series Analysis*. Here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Vd7MpjMlem554zieN-VxmuF-jsR2RBYgGDjvce1KZKk) to my data. It is monthly data, starting from June 2008 until December 2016. I'm trying to build the `ARIMA` model on it.

First, I split the data into training and testing sets. The testing set contains data from 12 months in 2016.

```
# Spare the last year for testing
trainData <- df[1:91, ]
testData <- df[92:103, ]
```

Create the time series for the `trainData`

```
# Create time series
trainData.ts <-
  ts(trainData$total,
     frequency = 12,
     start = c(2008, 6))
plot(
  trainData.ts,
  xlab = "Year",
  xaxp = c(2008, 2016, 8),
  main = "Training Data"
)
```

And here is the plot:
[image: Train Data]

Then, I decompose the data.
[image: Decomposed Data]

Finally, I build an `ARIMA` model, make a prediction, plot it together with the testing data.

```
# Build ARIMA model
model <- auto.arima(trainData.ts)

# Forecast the next 12 months
prediction <- forecast(model, h = 12)

# Plot the prediction and the Test Data
plot(prediction, xlab = "Lag (year)", xaxp = c(2008, 2018, 10))
lines(testData.ts, col = "red")
```

Here is my model:

```
> model
Series: trainData.ts 
ARIMA(0,1,2)                    

Coefficients:
          ma1      ma2
      -0.7115  -0.1775
s.e.   0.1130   0.1123

sigma^2 estimated as 118.3:  log likelihood=-342.23
AIC=690.45   AICc=690.73   BIC=697.95
```

And the plot of my prediction:
[image: Forecast]

From the plot, I can see that my prediction is too different from the test data. I would like to know why. Did I do anything wrong? Or could you suggest me a better way for this?

Thank you so much for your help.

### EDIT 2

I cleaned the data a bit. Then I force the `auto.arima()` to difference the seasonality by using

```
model <- auto.arima(trainData.ts, D = 1)
```

It seems the result is better with lower AIC, AICc, BIC.

```
> model
Series: trainData.ts 
ARIMA(1,0,0)(2,1,1)[12] with drift         

Coefficients:
         ar1     sar1     sar2     sma1    drift
      0.1844  -0.2707  -0.0719  -0.8335  -0.1849
s.e.  0.1187   0.2253   0.1967   0.3912   0.0409

sigma^2 estimated as 107.5:  log likelihood=-304.28
AIC=620.57   AICc=621.73   BIC=634.78
```

[image: Prediction 2016]

Comment: Can you show the estimated model (`print(model)`)? It looks like your model has no seasonal components. I wonder why.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added my `model`. Please take a look.

Comment: That's what I thought. The model does not contain seasonal components. Maybe the seasonal fluctuations are found too small to be predictable with enough accuracy. You could experiment to force them into your model and see how it performs. Also, the fact that the forecast does not look like the data used to produce it should not necessarily come as a surprise. If your data was a random walk, your best forecast would be a horizontal line – very much unlike the historical development, but still the best there is...

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. I just tried and it gave a better result. What do you think about this? :) Is my prediction good or bad?

Comment: Information criteria are incomparable for original vs. differenced data, so lower AIC does not tell anything. But if forecast errors are smaller (check MSE, MAE, MAPE or similar for the out-of-sample period), then the model may be more appropriate.

Comment: For test set, my `MAE = 8.59` and `MAPE = 35.86`. I think those values are high, aren't they? Does it mean my prediction is not good? What should I do to improve it?

Comment: MAE depends on scale, so depending on the data `8.59` can be good or bad. MAPE does not depend on scale, but it's goodness must be judged depending on the context. If your series is highly predictable, `35.86` can be a lot, but if a series is mostly just noise, then it may be fine.

Comment: Ah, I see. You're explanation is great! Thank you! Base on the plot of my decomposition, I think that my data is not highly predictable because the season and trend are not clear while the noise is large. Am I correct?

Comment: Looking at your seasonal-trend-remainder decomposition, remainder has the highest amplitude while trend and seasonal have smaller; so you are right.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much, Richard! I have learned a lot from this. I'm just a newbie in Data Science, but I love it. I hope we can keep in touch in the future. Thanks again ^^

Comment: I am glad I could help. Good luck in your further studies! To wrap up the thread, I may write an answer (over the next couple of days). If you come back here, you may accept it, then the thread will be "completed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From the plot, I can see that my prediction is too different from the test data. I would like to know why. Did I do anything wrong?

The model does not contain seasonal components. Maybe the seasonal fluctuations are found too small to be predictable with enough accuracy (by the OCSB test). You could experiment to force them into your model and see how it performs.

Also, the fact that the forecast does not look like the data used to produce it should not necessarily come as a surprise. If your data was a random walk, your best forecast would be a horizontal line – very much unlike the historical development, but still the best there is.

---

> I cleaned the data a bit. Then I force the `auto.arima` to difference the seasonality by using `model <- auto.arima(trainData.ts, D = 1)`. It seems the result is better with lower AIC, AICc, BIC.

Information criteria are not directly comparable for original vs. differenced data, so AIC comparison is not useful. But if forecast errors are smaller (check MSE, MAE, MAPE or similar for the out-of-sample period), then the model may be more appropriate.

---

> For test set, my `MAE = 8.59` and `MAPE = 35.86`. I think those values are high, aren't they? Does it mean my prediction is not good? What should I do to improve it?

MAE depends on scale, so depending on the data `8.59` can be good or bad. MAPE does not depend on scale, but it's goodness must be judged depending on the context. If your series is highly predictable, `35.86` can be a lot, but if a series is mostly just noise, then it may be fine.

---

> Base on the plot of my decomposition, I think that my data is not highly predictable because the season and trend are not clear while the noise is large. Am I correct?

Looking at your seasonal-trend-remainder decomposition, remainder has the highest amplitude while trend and seasonal have smaller; so you are right.